# Why does giving bias constraint to a view in Constraintlayout impacts resize animation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to implement resize animation with `ConstraintLayout` as root layout.

Here is my code:

```
 AdditiveAnimator().targets(waveView).setDuration(2000) 
                    .height((waveView.height.toFloat()*1.5f).toInt())
                    .width((waveView.width.toFloat()*1.5).toInt())
                    .setInterpolator( DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)
                    .start()
```

Note that this is a third party animation library.

And this is my XML of view:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/wave_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_160sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_160sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/wave_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35"
    />
```

This cause the animation to be unbalanced. What I mean is following:

[image: result with bias]

Now when I remove the bias the result is:

[image: result without bias]

What should I do to achieve desired results. Should I use another root layout?

Comment: Not clear what the issue is. The bias positions the view between the constraints. For you view those vertical constraints are top and bottom of the `ConstraintLayout`. The bias positions the view 35% of the way between those two constraints. The default is 50% which is the center and that is why you see the view centered when bias is deleted. Still, it's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: @Cheticamp the animation of the circle is not symmetrical when given bias of 0.3 but not when bias is none